# Equivalent of Irish domiciled ETFs for individual stocks

Tags: taxes, investing

ETFs, following for example the US stock markets, are often offered domiciled in Ireland because of favorable taxation conditions. Is there an equivalent thing for individual stocks? Say I want to buy some stock, for example Netflix, I would have to look into the local (in this case US) taxation law to see whether they are acceptable. I also have to find out whether it means I have file for US taxes. It would be easier if the same principles that apply to ETFs would also apply here. Does a similar mechanism exist?

---

P.S. I happen to be a French tax resident at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

This might point you in the right direction: **in the US**, if you want to buy shares of a foreign stock  you look to see if there's an "ADR" on a US stock exchange for that foreign company; you don't pay foreign taxes..  For example, my ex-wife owns ADRs in the Dutch company Ahold Delhaize, and got (I don't know what happens now) a dividend check from them every year.

We paid **US income tax** on those dividends.

Comment: ADRs are supposed to be subject to issuer-country tax by withholding and that has happened on every one I've held as a US individual at a (well-known) broker. On my statement I saw dividend +$x then withholding -$fractionofx every time. If your ex held directly (at the ADR level) the depository should have done that. (In contrast cap gains are taxed by the holder's jurisdiction.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 interesting.  The amounts were so small, I mat not have noticed it.